# Is there an $\ell_1$ isoperimetric inequality?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be some set and imagine we're in the $\ell_1$-metric so $\| x - y \| = \sum_{i=1}^n | x_i - y_i | $. Let $B(A, \epsilon)$ denote the union of $\epsilon$-radius $\ell_1$-balls around the points in $A$. Informally, what `shape' $A$ makes it so the change in volume $\mathrm{Vol}(B(A, \epsilon)) - \mathrm{Vol}(A)$ is minimized?

I think this change should be controlled by the surface area of $A$, so it should be connected to the existence of isoperimetric inequality for $\ell_1$.

Any pointer / references / hints would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I can improve the quality of this question in any way.